# Can we read Json file payload one by one

Tags: java, json, gson, testng, dataprovider

We have 2 records in json file , I want to read  it one by one and send it to rest api . 
can we get these records in a list or this record can be read one by one not in single payload . how can we split it ?

```
  {
    "batchSize": 0,
    "debug": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "firstName": "Maria Farj Hassan",
            "address": {
                "postcode": "100001",
                "longitude": 180
            },
            "birthDay": "1980-06-30",
            "startTime": 1485167477,
            "_meta": {
                "type": "customer.dedup",
                "id": "1",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "businessId": "1",

            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Second Record is ::

```
 {
        "batchSize": 0,
        "debug": true,
        "records": [
            {
                "firstName": "Maria  Hassan",
                "address": {
                    "postcode": "100001",
                    "longitude": 180
                },
                "birthDay": "1980-06-30",
                "partyType": 1,
                "startTime": 1485167477,
                "_meta": {
                    "type": "customer.dedup",
                    "id": "1",
                    "status": "ACTIVE"

                }
            }

        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Json file looks like below (I have merely combined both your records into a JSON array)

```
[
  {
    "batchSize": 0,
    "debug": true,
    "records": [
      {
        "firstName": "Maria  Hassan",
        "address": {
          "postcode": "100001",
          "longitude": 180
        },
        "birthDay": "1980-06-30",
        "partyType": 1,
        "startTime": 1485167477,
        "_meta": {
          "type": "customer.dedup",
          "id": "1",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchSize": 0,
    "debug": true,
    "records": [
      {
        "firstName": "Maria Farj Hassan",
        "address": {
          "postcode": "100001",
          "longitude": 180
        },
        "birthDay": "1980-06-30",
        "startTime": 1485167477,
        "_meta": {
          "type": "customer.dedup",
          "id": "1",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "businessId": "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here's a sample code that shows how to use this json file with a data provider.

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class TestSample {
    @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    public void testMethod(JsonElement record) {
        System.err.println("Data : " + record.getAsJsonObject().toString());
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] getData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        JsonArray array = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("src/test/resources/49466822.json")).getAsJsonArray();
        Object[][] data = new Object[array.size()][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = array.get(i);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

You need to add the below as a Maven dependency (Google gson dependency)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```